# Is there a package to truncate text overflowing a fixed width AND height?

Tags: packages

I'm trying to mix LaTeX and Python to generate small reference cards, with data fetched over the internet.

The problem I have, is that sometimes, the text fetched can be way too long for the card, and it will naturally overflow into a new page.

I'm basically looking for something that works exactly the same way as the `truncate` package, **but where I can also specify the height** of the box, so it allows the text to linebreak up until that point, before actually truncating the text.

Can this be performed in LaTeX, or am I better off truncating the text from the Python side of things ?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from `clipbox` you can also clip using TikZ. In the example below the clipping region is defined first as a 10 by 2 rectangle, and the text is positioned within that rectangle, causing the text to be vertically truncated.

Note that TikZ uses x,y coordinates with `(0,0)` in the bottom left (as in a mathematical function plot), therefore the top left (where the text should be placed) is `(0,max)`, in the example below `(0,2)`. Additionally, in the example the anchor is specified as `north west`, meaning that the top left of the node will be drawn at the provided coordinates (instead of the center of the node, which is the default).

If you don't want the frame you should remove the `draw` option from `\clip`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip[draw] (0,0) rectangle (10,2);
\node [align=justify, text width=9.5cm, anchor=north west] (text) at (0,2) {\lipsum[3]};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is not exactly clear what you intend with "truncate" since I don't know that package.  But with a `\clipbox`, you may be able to achieve your goal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\textsf{original text in 10cm wide parbox}\smallskip

\parbox{10cm}{\lipsum[3]}

\bigskip
\textsf{Version of above box clipped to  8cm x 3cm:}\smallskip

\setbox0=\hbox{\parbox[b]{10cm}{\lipsum[3]}}
\clipbox{0pt \dimexpr\ht0-3cm\relax{} 2cm 0pt}{\copy0}

\bigskip
\textsf{First 10 wrapped lines of original box in a 5cm wide box:}\smallskip

\setbox0=\hbox{\parbox[t]{5cm}{\lipsum[3]}}
\clipbox{0pt \dimexpr\dp0-9\baselineskip\relax{} 0in 0pt}{\copy0}
\end{document}
```

[image]